# Android - Send a notification on a date and hour defined

Tags: android, notifications, alarm

How can I send a notification like a reminder, even the application are closed.

For example, when we register an event on calendar and the calendar send a notification 10 minutes (i.e.) before event start. How can I do that on my application??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most appropriate mechanism available in Android for doing this would most likely be the system alarms.

Alarms allow you to execute a piece of code at a given point in time. Even if your app is not currently working or the phone is sleeping.

To learn more about alarms visit the official developers reference [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: Yes. An AlarmManager coupled with a BroadcastReceiver is what you are looking for. Check Paul's link.